# SSL Certificate is only updated in localhost but not in domain

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, webserver

I am using apache2.4.53 and I have renewed the SSL certificate and it's renewed when I access the website through the localhost or IP only, but when I access it through the domain it keeps getting me the old certificate

Comment: Do you have any load balancer in front on apache? If yes then you have to update there as well.
If still not working, try to clear clear Browser cache.

Comment: hello @mksmanjit actually I don't have any load balancer and I cleared browser cache, it's only updated on localhost but when I access the website through the domain it gets me the old certificate 

also it works when I access the website through the webserver even If I write the full domain in the webserver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479227/ssl-renew-certificate-on-apache-keeps-using-old-certtificate-file
Check this may be it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that there was a proxy on the server